# SQL Query: How to pull counts of two coulmns from respective tables

Tags: sql

Given two tables:

1st Table Name: `FACETS_Business_NPI_Provider`

```
Buss_ID NPI Bussiness_Desc
11          222         Eleven 222
12          223         Twelve 223
13          224         Thirteen 224
14          225         Fourteen 225
11          226         Eleven 226
12          227         Tweleve 227
12          228         Tweleve 228
```

2nd Table :  `FACETS_PROVIDERs_Practitioners`

```
NPI     PRAC_NO        PROV_NAME  PRAC_NAME
222         943         P222    PR943
222         942         P222    PR942
223         931         P223    PR931
224         932         P224    PR932
224         933         P224    PR933
226         950         P226    PR950
227         951         P227    PR951
228         952         P228    PR952
228         953         P228    PR953
```

With below query I'm getting following results whereas it is expected to have the provider counts from table `FACETS_Business_NPI_Provider` (i.e. 3 instead of 4 for `Buss_Id` 12 and 2 instead of 3 for `Buss_Id` 11, etc).

```
SELECT BP.Buss_ID, 
  COUNT(BP.NPI) PROVIDER_COUNT, 
  COUNT(PP.PRAC_NO)PRACTITIONER_COUNT
FROM FACETS_Business_NPI_Provider BP
LEFT JOIN FACETS_PROVIDERs_Practitioners PP 
  ON PP.NOI=BP.NPI
group by BP.Buss_ID

Buss_ID PROVIDER_COUNT  PRACTITIONER_COUNT
11          3   3
12          4   4
13          2   2
14          1   0
```

Comment: Can you confirm which type of database you're using (MySQL,MSSQL etc) and which version.

Comment: Jon:  I'm trying above in SQL Server but I need a query for ORACLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you might want to add a DISTINCT clause to the columns.

Here is an SQL Fiddle, which we can probably use to discuss further.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9a0e6/3

Comment: Geordee: I'm looking for following from the information available in above mentioned two tables:

Comment: Thank you Geordee, I checked above URL and this is exactly I was looking for.